# How does a nothing compared to negative numbers in python?

Tags: python, comparison

Check the following argument `(1, 2) < (1, 2, -1)`
It will evaluate to **true**.
So, is it true that `nothing/null` is always less then **any** value?

Comment: shorter sequences are considered smaller, the elements are compared in each and if equal the length will win

Comment: ahhhh...Thanks, they missed that on the tutorial I read :-)

Comment: No worries, it is the same for lists as far as I know.